# this.paginatior is undefined

Tags: angular, pagination

I am trying to achieve pagination for the mat-table. But i am getting this.paginatior is undefined when I console the paginatior variable.

```
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

export class DataComponent implements OnInit{
    public dataSource:MatTableDataSource<any>;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.fetchdata.getdata().subscribe(result=>{
             let resultData = result.data;
             this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(resultData);
             this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
    }
}
```

In HTML

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: did you try  in ngAfterViewInit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're dealing with async data in a `mat-table`, set the pagination in your `ngAfterViewInit` after you fetch the data.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.fetchdata.getdata().subscribe(result=>{
         let resultData = result.data;
         this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(resultData);
         this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> When are variables injected via @ViewChild available? The value of
>   this injected member variable is not immediately available at
>   component construction time!
>
> Angular will fill in this property automatically, but only later in
>   the component lifecycle, after the view initialization is completed.

So use this.paginator after initialiation.

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined`
this is show when it is given in ngAfterViewInit